# How can I make a long and wide table fit the text width?

Tags: tables, longtable

My table is too wide and too long to fit in one page. I want to separate it in 2 pages.
I used `longtable` package to separate it in two pages but I can't fix the width.

Here is my table code, (it look a little mess, sorry about that but if you copy and paste to your latex you see it better).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}    
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}

\caption{aaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aa}\\

\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Nuclei} & \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering Data\\Range}} & \multirow{2}{*}{$\sigma$}  & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{CT} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{BSFG} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{L}\\
\cline{4-12}
&   &   &  $T$ & $\Delta$ &  $\chi^2$   &  $a$  &  $\Delta$  & $\chi^2$  & $a_L$   & $\Delta$  &  $\chi^2$ \\
\hline
\multirow{9}{*}{\textsuperscript{76}As} & \multirow{3}{*}{ \parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 2-82\\RIPL-3\\disc.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 1.33 & -5.43 & 23.65 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
\cline{3-12}
&   & GC & - & - & - & 5.60 & 4.43 & 23.33 & 3.02 & 2.33 & 23.05 \\
\cline{3-12}
& & RB & - & - & - & 5.84 & 4.91 & 23.34 & 3.36 & 2.97 & 23.11 \\
\cline{2-12}
& \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 2-82\\RIPL-3\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.95 & -3.43 & 31.31 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
\cline{3-12}
& & GC & - & - & - & 9.73 & 1.92 & 58.40 & 5.43 & 0.66 & 79.69 \\
\cline{3-12}
& & RB & - & - & - & 10.70 & 1.81 & 74.46 & 3.75 & 2.42 & 113.09 \\
\cline{2-12}
& \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 6-27\\Koning\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.95 & -3.51 & 1.74 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
\cline{3-12}
& & GC & - & - & - & 9.90 & 1.97 & 1.48 & 5.80 & 0.67 & 1.34 \\
\cline{3-12}
& & RB & - & - & - & 10.85 & 1.84 & 1.41 & 7.04 & 0.64 & 1.23 \\
\hline
\multirow{9}{*}{\textsuperscript{198}Au} & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 3-91\\disc.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.81 & -2.69 & 13.61 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
\cline{3-12}
&   & GC & - & - & - & 9.01 & 2.43 & 13.21 & 4.81 & 1.12 & 12.74 \\
\cline{3-12}
& & RB & - & - & - & 9.55 & 2.82 & 13.24 & 5.50 & 1.63 & 12.87 \\
\cline{2-12}
& \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 13-91\\RIPL-3\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.60 & -1.65 & 22.35 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
\cline{3-12}
& & GC & - & - & - & 15.93 & 0.78 & 60.16 & 9.70 & -0.085 & 99.79 \\
\cline{3-12}
& & RB & - & - & - & 18.47 & 0.70 & 84.45 & 12.38 & -0.11 & 156.17 \\
\cline{2-12}
& \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 3-91\\Koning\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.60 & -1.62 & 4.37 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
\cline{3-12}
& & GC & - & - & - & 15.68 & 0.96 & 3.69 & 9.50 & 0.15 & 3.11 \\
\cline{3-12}
& & RB & - & - & - & 18.08 & 0.93 & 3.43 & 12.05 & 0.19 & 2.66 \\
\hline
\multirow{9}{*}{\textsuperscript{138}Ba} & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 4-50\\RIPL-3\\disc.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 1.28 & -1.34 & 2.97 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
\cline{3-12}
&   & GC & - & - & - & 5.68 & 0.98 & 3.29 & 2.87 & -0.84 & 3.39 \\
\cline{3-12}
& & RB & - & - & - & 6.06 & 1.67 & 3.29 & 3.35 & -0.09 & 3.37 \\
\cline{2-12}
& \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 4-50\\RIPL-3\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.73 & 0.77 & 1.65 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
\cline{3-12}
& & GC & - & - & - & 5.33 & 0.90 & 25.6 & 3.34 & -1.29 & 28.11 \\
\cline{3-12}
& & RB & - & - & - & 6.33 & 1.40 & 29.93 & 3.41 & -0.09 & 30.21 \\
\cline{2-12}
& \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 8-21\\Koning\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.73 & 0.70 & 0.52 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
\cline{3-12}
& & GC & - & - & - & 11.21 & -1.22 & 0.62 & 6.33 & -2.25 & 0.67 \\
\cline{3-12}
& & RB & - & - & - & 13.22 & -1.29 & 0.72 & 8.44 & -2.19 & 1.04 \\
\hline
\multirow{9}{*}{\textsuperscript{60}Co} & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 7-65\\disc.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 1.03 & -1.93 & 1.74 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
\cline{3-12}
&   & GC & - & - & - & 5.68 & 0.98 & 3.29 & 3.24 & -0.02 & 1.46 \\
\cline{3-12}
& & RB & - & - & - & 6.05 & 1.66 & 3.28 & 3.57 & 0.43 & 1.46 \\
\cline{2-12}
& \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 10-65\\RIPL-3\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 1.17 & -2.54 & 2.31 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
\cline{3-12}
& & GC & - & - & - & 6.95 & 1.26 & 1.91 & 3.94 & -0.46 & 4.23 \\
\cline{3-12}
& & RB & - & - & - & 7.58 & 1.23 & 2.66 & 4.60 & -0.32 & 7.43 \\
\cline{2-12}
& \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 7-15\\Koning\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 1.13 & -2.13 & 0.11 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
\cline{3-12}
& & GC & - & - & - & 7.03 & 1.17 & 0.11 & 3.95 & -0.41 & 0.11 \\
\cline{3-12}
& & RB & - & - & - & 7.62 & 1.22 & 0.11 & 4.59 & -0.18 & 0.14 \\
\hline
\multirow{9}{*}{\textsuperscript{166}Ho} & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 2-154\\disc.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.53 & -1.60 & 76.29 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
\cline{3-12}
&   & GC & - & - & - & 13.84 & 1.37 & 69.13 & 7.41 & 0.54 & 63.03 \\
\cline{3-12}
& & RB & - & - & - & 14.37 & 1.54 & 69.34 & 8.18 & 0.78 & 64.23 \\
\cline{2-12}
& \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 11-154\\RIPL-3\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.60 & -2.07 & 42.44 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
\cline{3-12}
& & GC & - & - & - & 9.52 & 2.65 & 84.46 & 5.20 & 1.39 & 84.82 \\
\cline{3-12}
& & RB & - & - & - & 9.75 & 3.13 & 86.47 & 5.73 & 1.89 & 88.53 \\
\cline{2-12}
& \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 2-16\\Koning\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.56 & -1.49 & 0.79 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
\cline{3-12}
& & GC & - & - & - & 17.76 & 0.78 & 0.48 & 10.96 & 0.08 & 0.43 \\
\cline{3-12}
& & RB & - & - & - & 19.42 & 0.79 & 0.45 & 12.09 & 0.14 & 0.48 \\
\hline
\pagebreak
\caption{xxxx}\\
\hline
\multirow{9}{*}{\textsuperscript{139}La} & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 4-33\\RIPL-3\\disc.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 2.02 & -6.46 & 2.74 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
\cline{3-12}
&   & GC & - & - & - & 3.59 & 5.54 & 2.73 & 1.90 & 2.36 & 2.72 \\
\cline{3-12}
& & RB & - & - & - & 3.88 & 6.93 & 2.73 & 2.25 & 3.92 & 2.72 \\
\cline{2-12}
& \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 4-33\\RIPL-3\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.78 & -0.76 & 7.40 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
\cline{3-12}
& & GC & - & - & - & 4.27 & 4.11 & 30.97 & 2.08 & 1.88 & 31 \\
\cline{3-12}
& & RB & - & - & - & 4.03 & 6.50 & 31.13 & 2.30 & 3.74 & 31.14 \\
\cline{2-12}
& \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 4-21\\Koning\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.79 & -0.88 & 0.94 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
\cline{3-12}
& & GC & - & - & - & 11.63 & -0.01 & 0.91 & 7.07 & -1.08 & 1.23 \\
\cline{3-12}
& & RB & - & - & - & 12.94 & 0.02 & 0.97 & 8.42 & -0.95 & 1.51 \\
\hline

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! A quick hint: If you indent lines of LaTeX code by four spaces, they will automatically be pretty-printed by the site software. And, do take care to make the code compilable without much tinkering. (E.g., don't forget to supply the `\begin{document}` statement.)

Comment: If it is too wide, you really have three options: (1) reduce the font size; (2) rethink the way you present the data; (3) put the table on a page in landscape mode i.e. turn it through 90 degrees. So try to think about which of those options would work best for your audience.

Comment: How wide is the textblock of your document?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way of setting the table in landscape mode. I've also used `booktabs` to make things look a bit nicer, dispensing with the vertical rules. The only downside of combining `booktabs` and `longtable` is that you have to go through and comment out some rules in the middle of the table to avoid spurious double-rules. In this case, you also need to manage the page breaks manually. However, you were doing that already.

I've set this up to repeat the column heads on each page which is probably what you want as readers will not want to have to look back to a previous page to figure out what the numbers mean. Also, I'm not sure what the second `\caption` command was intended to do but it seemed to have no effect so I removed it, along with packages not required for your MWE.

This version has also benefited from henry's comment recommending some additional spacing to make the groupings of columns clearer. This space can obviously be adjusted to taste.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
  \label{eq:20}
  \begin{landscape}
    \begin{longtable}{c!{\hskip 10pt}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}!{\hskip 10pt}c!{\hskip 10pt}*{3}{c}!{\hskip 10pt}*{3}{c}!{\hskip 10pt}*{3}{c}}
      \caption{aaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aa}\\
      \toprule
      \multirow{2}{*}{Nuclei} & \multirow{2}{*}{\centering Data Range} & \multirow{2}{*}{$\sigma$}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{CT} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{BSFG} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{L}\\
      \cmidrule{4-12}
      &   &   &  $T$ & $\Delta$ &  $\chi^2$   &  $a$  &  $\Delta$  & $\chi^2$  & $a_L$   & $\Delta$  &  $\chi^2$ \\
      \midrule\endhead
      \bottomrule\endfoot
      \multirow{9}{*}{\textsuperscript{76}As} & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 2-82\\RIPL-3\\disc.}} & Eq.\ref{eq:20} & 1.33 & -5.43 & 23.65 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
      \cmidrule{3-12}
      &   & GC & - & - & - & 5.60 & 4.43 & 23.33 & 3.02 & 2.33 & 23.05 \\
      \cmidrule{3-12}
      & & RB & - & - & - & 5.84 & 4.91 & 23.34 & 3.36 & 2.97 & 23.11 \\
      \cmidrule{2-12}
      & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 2-82\\RIPL-3\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\ref{eq:20} & 0.95 & -3.43 & 31.31 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
      \cmidrule{3-12}
      & & GC & - & - & - & 9.73 & 1.92 & 58.40 & 5.43 & 0.66 & 79.69 \\
      \cmidrule{3-12}
      & & RB & - & - & - & 10.70 & 1.81 & 74.46 & 3.75 & 2.42 & 113.09 \\
      \cmidrule{2-12}
      & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 6-27\\Koning\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\ref{eq:20} & 0.95 & -3.51 & 1.74 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
      \cmidrule{3-12}
      & & GC & - & - & - & 9.90 & 1.97 & 1.48 & 5.80 & 0.67 & 1.34 \\
      \cmidrule{3-12}
      & & RB & - & - & - & 10.85 & 1.84 & 1.41 & 7.04 & 0.64 & 1.23 \\\midrule
      \multirow{9}{*}{\textsuperscript{198}Au} & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 3-91\\disc.}} & Eq.\ref{eq:20} & 0.81 & -2.69 & 13.61 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
      \cmidrule{3-12}
      &   & GC & - & - & - & 9.01 & 2.43 & 13.21 & 4.81 & 1.12 & 12.74 \\
      \cmidrule{3-12}
      & & RB & - & - & - & 9.55 & 2.82 & 13.24 & 5.50 & 1.63 & 12.87 \\
      \cmidrule{2-12}
      & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 13-91\\RIPL-3\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\ref{eq:20} & 0.60 & -1.65 & 22.35 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
      \cmidrule{3-12}
      & & GC & - & - & - & 15.93 & 0.78 & 60.16 & 9.70 & -0.085 & 99.79 \\
      \cmidrule{3-12}
      & & RB & - & - & - & 18.47 & 0.70 & 84.45 & 12.38 & -0.11 & 156.17 \\
      \pagebreak%\cmidrule{2-12}
      & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 3-91\\Koning\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\ref{eq:20} & 0.60 & -1.62 & 4.37 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
      \cmidrule{3-12}
      & & GC & - & - & - & 15.68 & 0.96 & 3.69 & 9.50 & 0.15 & 3.11 \\
      \cmidrule{3-12}
      & & RB & - & - & - & 18.08 & 0.93 & 3.43 & 12.05 & 0.19 & 2.66 \\\midrule
      \multirow{9}{*}{\textsuperscript{138}Ba} & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 4-50\\RIPL-3\\disc.}} & Eq.\ref{eq:20} & 1.28 & -1.34 & 2.97 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
      \cmidrule{3-12}
      &   & GC & - & - & - & 5.68 & 0.98 & 3.29 & 2.87 & -0.84 & 3.39 \\
      \cmidrule{3-12}
      & & RB & - & - & - & 6.06 & 1.67 & 3.29 & 3.35 & -0.09 & 3.37 \\
      \cmidrule{2-12}
      & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 4-50\\RIPL-3\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\ref{eq:20} & 0.73 & 0.77 & 1.65 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
      \cmidrule{3-12}
      & & GC & - & - & - & 5.33 & 0.90 & 25.6 & 3.34 & -1.29 & 28.11 \\
      \cmidrule{3-12}
      & & RB & - & - & - & 6.33 & 1.40 & 29.93 & 3.41 & -0.09 & 30.21 \\
      \cmidrule{2-12}
      & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 8-21\\Koning\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\ref{eq:20} & 0.73 & 0.70 & 0.52 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
      \cmidrule{3-12}
      & & GC & - & - & - & 11.21 & -1.22 & 0.62 & 6.33 & -2.25 & 0.67 \\
      \cmidrule{3-12}
      & & RB & - & - & - & 13.22 & -1.29 & 0.72 & 8.44 & -2.19 & 1.04 \\\midrule
      \multirow{5}{*}{\textsuperscript{60}Co} & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 7-65\\disc.}} & Eq.\ref{eq:20} & 1.03 & -1.93 & 1.74 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
      \cmidrule{3-12}
      &   & GC & - & - & - & 5.68 & 0.98 & 3.29 & 3.24 & -0.02 & 1.46 \\
      \cmidrule{3-12}
      & & RB & - & - & - & 6.05 & 1.66 & 3.28 & 3.57 & 0.43 & 1.46 \\
      \pagebreak%\cmidrule{2-12}
      & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 10-65\\RIPL-3\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\ref{eq:20} & 1.17 & -2.54 & 2.31 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
      \cmidrule{3-12}
      & & GC & - & - & - & 6.95 & 1.26 & 1.91 & 3.94 & -0.46 & 4.23 \\
      \cmidrule{3-12}
      & & RB & - & - & - & 7.58 & 1.23 & 2.66 & 4.60 & -0.32 & 7.43 \\
      \cmidrule{2-12}
      & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 7-15\\Koning\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\ref{eq:20} & 1.13 & -2.13 & 0.11 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
      \cmidrule{3-12}
      & & GC & - & - & - & 7.03 & 1.17 & 0.11 & 3.95 & -0.41 & 0.11 \\
      \cmidrule{3-12}
      & & RB & - & - & - & 7.62 & 1.22 & 0.11 & 4.59 & -0.18 & 0.14 \\\midrule
      \multirow{9}{*}{\textsuperscript{166}Ho} & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 2-154\\disc.}} & Eq.\ref{eq:20} & 0.53 & -1.60 & 76.29 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
      \cmidrule{3-12}
      &   & GC & - & - & - & 13.84 & 1.37 & 69.13 & 7.41 & 0.54 & 63.03 \\
      \cmidrule{3-12}
      & & RB & - & - & - & 14.37 & 1.54 & 69.34 & 8.18 & 0.78 & 64.23 \\
      \cmidrule{2-12}
      & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 11-154\\RIPL-3\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\ref{eq:20} & 0.60 & -2.07 & 42.44 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
      \cmidrule{3-12}
      & & GC & - & - & - & 9.52 & 2.65 & 84.46 & 5.20 & 1.39 & 84.82 \\
      \cmidrule{3-12}
      & & RB & - & - & - & 9.75 & 3.13 & 86.47 & 5.73 & 1.89 & 88.53 \\
      \cmidrule{2-12}
      & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 2-16\\Koning\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\ref{eq:20} & 0.56 & -1.49 & 0.79 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
      \cmidrule{3-12}
      & & GC & - & - & - & 17.76 & 0.78 & 0.48 & 10.96 & 0.08 & 0.43 \\
      \cmidrule{3-12}
      & & RB & - & - & - & 19.42 & 0.79 & 0.45 & 12.09 & 0.14 & 0.48 \\\pagebreak%\midrule
      \multirow{9}{*}{\textsuperscript{139}La} & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 4-33\\RIPL-3\\disc.}} & Eq.\ref{eq:20} & 2.02 & -6.46 & 2.74 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
      \cmidrule{3-12}
      &   & GC & - & - & - & 3.59 & 5.54 & 2.73 & 1.90 & 2.36 & 2.72 \\
      \cmidrule{3-12}
      & & RB & - & - & - & 3.88 & 6.93 & 2.73 & 2.25 & 3.92 & 2.72 \\
      \cmidrule{2-12}
      & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 4-33\\RIPL-3\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\ref{eq:20} & 0.78 & -0.76 & 7.40 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
      \cmidrule{3-12}
      & & GC & - & - & - & 4.27 & 4.11 & 30.97 & 2.08 & 1.88 & 31 \\
      \cmidrule{3-12}
      & & RB & - & - & - & 4.03 & 6.50 & 31.13 & 2.30 & 3.74 & 31.14 \\
      \cmidrule{2-12}
      & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 4-21\\Koning\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\ref{eq:20} & 0.79 & -0.88 & 0.94 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
      \cmidrule{3-12}
      & & GC & - & - & - & 11.63 & -0.01 & 0.91 & 7.07 & -1.08 & 1.23 \\
      \cmidrule{3-12}
      & & RB & - & - & - & 12.94 & 0.02 & 0.97 & 8.42 & -0.95 & 1.51 \\
    \end{longtable}
  \end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

If you look at the `booktabs` manual, you'll find further hints on presenting your table in the most effective and appealing way. In particular, you may wish to slightly shorten some of the inner rules and `booktabs` makes this extremely easy. (Warning: it contains strongly-expressed criticism of all uses of vertical rules in tables. I think it exaggerates the case and that they are *sometimes* helpful, even though I agree that they are unnecessary clutter in *most* cases. Obviously, you may disagree with both me and `booktabs`'s author!)

[image: table in landscape]

Alternatively, you *could* either adjust the page margins for the pages containing the table or make the font smaller. However, I'd encourage you to do neither unless you really have to. Consistent margins should not be sacrificed too readily, I think. (Sometimes I think it is worth doing for a graphic but not for a table which *can* be split.) And making the text smaller will make the table more difficult to parse and read.

Comment: In such a case, I'd insert some spacing between the columns because the grouping isn't very clear (to me).

Comment: @henry Thanks for suggesting that. I think that does make it look clearer although I wasn't sure how much would be the 'right' amount of additional space. (I'm also not certain if this is the best way to add it.)

Comment: @cfr :) Hm, another idea. Genuinely no idea why I had *just* thought of it, but I'd also set the space to, say, `2pt` (or 3 or 4, it probably requires some T&E) between the columns which belong together and are grouped in contrast to some bigger space between the different column groups.

Answer (score 4):

copied from the duplicate question:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

{\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{1.4pt}
 \begin{longtable}{@{}|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|@{}}

 \caption{aaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aa}\\

 \hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{Nuclei} & \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering Data\\Range}} &           \multirow{2}{*}{$\sigma$}  & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{CT} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{BSFG} &    \multicolumn{3}{c|}{L}\\
  \cline{4-12}
 &   &   &  $T$ & $\Delta$ &  $\chi^2$   &  $a$  &  $\Delta$  & $\chi^2$  & $a_L$   &     $\Delta$  &  $\chi^2$ \\
 \hline
 \multirow{9}{*}{\textsuperscript{76}As} & \multirow{3}{*}{ \parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering      2-82\\RIPL-3\\disc.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 1.33 & -5.43 & 23.65 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
 \cline{3-12}
 &   & GC & - & - & - & 5.60 & 4.43 & 23.33 & 3.02 & 2.33 & 23.05 \\
  \cline{3-12}
   & & RB & - & - & - & 5.84 & 4.91 & 23.34 & 3.36 & 2.97 & 23.11 \\
  \cline{2-12}
   & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 2-82\\RIPL-3\\disc.+res.}} &      Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.95 & -3.43 & 31.31 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
  \cline{3-12}
   & & GC & - & - & - & 9.73 & 1.92 & 58.40 & 5.43 & 0.66 & 79.69 \\
   \cline{3-12}
   & & RB & - & - & - & 10.70 & 1.81 & 74.46 & 3.75 & 2.42 & 113.09 \\
   \cline{2-12}
  & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 6-27\\Koning\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20}       & 0.95 & -3.51 & 1.74 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & GC & - & - & - & 9.90 & 1.97 & 1.48 & 5.80 & 0.67 & 1.34 \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & RB & - & - & - & 10.85 & 1.84 & 1.41 & 7.04 & 0.64 & 1.23 \\
  \hline
  \multirow{9}{*}{\textsuperscript{198}Au} & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 3-91\\disc.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.81 & -2.69 & 13.61 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
  \cline{3-12}
  &   & GC & - & - & - & 9.01 & 2.43 & 13.21 & 4.81 & 1.12 & 12.74 \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & RB & - & - & - & 9.55 & 2.82 & 13.24 & 5.50 & 1.63 & 12.87 \\
  \cline{2-12}
  & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 13-91\\RIPL-3\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20}       & 0.60 & -1.65 & 22.35 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & GC & - & - & - & 15.93 & 0.78 & 60.16 & 9.70 & -0.085 & 99.79 \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & RB & - & - & - & 18.47 & 0.70 & 84.45 & 12.38 & -0.11 & 156.17 \\
  \cline{2-12}
  & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 3-91\\Koning\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20}       & 0.60 & -1.62 & 4.37 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & GC & - & - & - & 15.68 & 0.96 & 3.69 & 9.50 & 0.15 & 3.11 \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & RB & - & - & - & 18.08 & 0.93 & 3.43 & 12.05 & 0.19 & 2.66 \\
  \hline
  \multirow{9}{*}{\textsuperscript{138}Ba} & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 4-50\\RIPL-3\\disc.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 1.28 & -1.34 & 2.97 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
  \cline{3-12}
  &   & GC & - & - & - & 5.68 & 0.98 & 3.29 & 2.87 & -0.84 & 3.39 \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & RB & - & - & - & 6.06 & 1.67 & 3.29 & 3.35 & -0.09 & 3.37 \\
  \cline{2-12}
  & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 4-50\\RIPL-3\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20}       & 0.73 & 0.77 & 1.65 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & GC & - & - & - & 5.33 & 0.90 & 25.6 & 3.34 & -1.29 & 28.11 \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & RB & - & - & - & 6.33 & 1.40 & 29.93 & 3.41 & -0.09 & 30.21 \\
  \cline{2-12}
  & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 8-21\\Koning\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20}       & 0.73 & 0.70 & 0.52 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & GC & - & - & - & 11.21 & -1.22 & 0.62 & 6.33 & -2.25 & 0.67 \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & RB & - & - & - & 13.22 & -1.29 & 0.72 & 8.44 & -2.19 & 1.04 \\
  \hline
  \multirow{9}{*}{\textsuperscript{60}Co} & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 7-65\\disc.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 1.03 & -1.93 & 1.74 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
  \cline{3-12}
  &   & GC & - & - & - & 5.68 & 0.98 & 3.29 & 3.24 & -0.02 & 1.46 \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & RB & - & - & - & 6.05 & 1.66 & 3.28 & 3.57 & 0.43 & 1.46 \\
  \cline{2-12}
  & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 10-65\\RIPL-3\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20}       & 1.17 & -2.54 & 2.31 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & GC & - & - & - & 6.95 & 1.26 & 1.91 & 3.94 & -0.46 & 4.23 \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & RB & - & - & - & 7.58 & 1.23 & 2.66 & 4.60 & -0.32 & 7.43 \\
  \cline{2-12}
  & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 7-15\\Koning\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20}       & 1.13 & -2.13 & 0.11 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & GC & - & - & - & 7.03 & 1.17 & 0.11 & 3.95 & -0.41 & 0.11 \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & RB & - & - & - & 7.62 & 1.22 & 0.11 & 4.59 & -0.18 & 0.14 \\
  \hline
  \multirow{9}{*}{\textsuperscript{166}Ho} & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering       2-154\\disc.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.53 & -1.60 & 76.29 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
  \cline{3-12}
  &   & GC & - & - & - & 13.84 & 1.37 & 69.13 & 7.41 & 0.54 & 63.03 \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & RB & - & - & - & 14.37 & 1.54 & 69.34 & 8.18 & 0.78 & 64.23 \\
  \cline{2-12}
  & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 11-154\\RIPL-3\\disc.+res.}} &       Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.60 & -2.07 & 42.44 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & GC & - & - & - & 9.52 & 2.65 & 84.46 & 5.20 & 1.39 & 84.82 \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & RB & - & - & - & 9.75 & 3.13 & 86.47 & 5.73 & 1.89 & 88.53 \\
  \cline{2-12}
  & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 2-16\\Koning\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20}      & 0.56 & -1.49 & 0.79 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & GC & - & - & - & 17.76 & 0.78 & 0.48 & 10.96 & 0.08 & 0.43 \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & RB & - & - & - & 19.42 & 0.79 & 0.45 & 12.09 & 0.14 & 0.48 \\
  \hline
  \pagebreak
  \caption{xxxx}\\
  \hline
    \multirow{9}{*}{\textsuperscript{139}La} & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 4-     33\\RIPL-3\\disc.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 2.02 & -6.46 & 2.74 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
     \cline{3-12}
     &   & GC & - & - & - & 3.59 & 5.54 & 2.73 & 1.90 & 2.36 & 2.72 \\
    \cline{3-12}
    & & RB & - & - & - & 3.88 & 6.93 & 2.73 & 2.25 & 3.92 & 2.72 \\
    \cline{2-12}
    & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 4-33\\RIPL-3\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20}      & 0.78 & -0.76 & 7.40 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
   \cline{3-12}
   & & GC & - & - & - & 4.27 & 4.11 & 30.97 & 2.08 & 1.88 & 31 \\
  \cline{3-12}
    & & RB & - & - & - & 4.03 & 6.50 & 31.13 & 2.30 & 3.74 & 31.14 \\
     \cline{2-12}
     & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 4-21\\Koning\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20}       & 0.79 & -0.88 & 0.94 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
    \cline{3-12}
    & & GC & - & - & - & 11.63 & -0.01 & 0.91 & 7.07 & -1.08 & 1.23 \\
   \cline{3-12}
   & & RB & - & - & - & 12.94 & 0.02 & 0.97 & 8.42 & -0.95 & 1.51 \\
   \hline

   \end{longtable}}

   \end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have one-inch wide horizontal margins, all you need to do to make the table fit into the width of the text block is to reduce the length parameter `\tabcolsep` to about `5pt` (default is `6pt`). I would suggest, actually, that you use the method described on page 5 of the user guide of the longtable package to make the table occupy automatically the full width of the text block. How to do this is illustrated in the example below.

Next, you should consider (a) using the macros of the `booktabs` package to draw well-spaced *horizontal lines* and (b) not drawing any *vertical lines*.

Finally, I would recommend you use the `S` column type of the `siunitx` package to typeset the numbers in columns 4 thru 12. Doing so will align the numbers on their decimal markers and automatically typeset the `-` symbols as mathematical minus symbols.

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx,booktabs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\begin{document}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt} % default value: 6pt
\begin{longtable}{@{} l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} l l *{9}{S[table-format=2.2]} @{}}
\caption{aaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aa}\\
\toprule
Nuclei & Data Range & $\sigma$  
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{CT} 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{BSFG} 
& \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{L}\\
\cmidrule{4-6} \cmidrule{7-9} \cmidrule{10-12}
& & & {$T$} & {$\Delta$} &  {$\chi^2$} &  {$a$} &  {$\Delta$} & {$\chi^2$} & {$a_L$} & {$\Delta$} &  {$\chi^2$} \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
Nuclei & Data Range & $\sigma$  
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{CT} 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{BSFG} 
& \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{L}\\
\cmidrule{4-6} \cmidrule{7-9} \cmidrule{10-12}
& & & {$T$} & {$\Delta$} &  {$\chi^2$} &  {$a$} &  {$\Delta$} & {$\chi^2$} & {$a_L$} & {$\Delta$} &  {$\chi^2$} \\
\midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
\textsuperscript{76}As & \multirow{3}{*}{ \parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 2-82\\RIPL-3\\disc.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 1.33 & -5.43 & 23.65 & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$}  \\
%%\cline{3-12}
& & GC & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 5.60 & 4.43 & 23.33 & 3.02 & 2.33 & 23.05 \\
%%\cline{3-12}
& & RB & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 5.84 & 4.91 & 23.34 & 3.36 & 2.97 & 23.11 \\
\cmidrule(l){2-12}
& \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 2-82\\RIPL-3\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.95 & -3.43 & 31.31 & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$}  \\
%%\cline{3-12}
& & GC & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 9.73 & 1.92 & 58.40 & 5.43 & 0.66 & 79.69 \\
%%\cline{3-12}
& & RB & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 10.70 & 1.81 & 74.46 & 3.75 & 2.42 & 113.09 \\
\cmidrule(l){2-12}
& \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 6-27\\Koning\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.95 & -3.51 & 1.74 & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$}  \\
%%\cline{3-12}
& & GC & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 9.90 & 1.97 & 1.48 & 5.80 & 0.67 & 1.34 \\
%%\cline{3-12}
& & RB & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 10.85 & 1.84 & 1.41 & 7.04 & 0.64 & 1.23 \\
\midrule
\textsuperscript{198}Au & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 3-91\\disc.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.81 & -2.69 & 13.61 & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$}  \\
%%\cline{3-12}
& & GC & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 9.01 & 2.43 & 13.21 & 4.81 & 1.12 & 12.74 \\
%%\cline{3-12}
& & RB & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 9.55 & 2.82 & 13.24 & 5.50 & 1.63 & 12.87 \\
\cmidrule(l){2-12}
& \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 13-91\\RIPL-3\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.60 & -1.65 & 22.35 & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$}  \\
%%\cline{3-12}
& & GC & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 15.93 & 0.78 & 60.16 & 9.70 & -0.085 & 99.79 \\
%%\cline{3-12}
& & RB & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 18.47 & 0.70 & 84.45 & 12.38 & -0.11 & 156.17 \\
\cmidrule(l){2-12}
& \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 3-91\\Koning\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.60 & -1.62 & 4.37 & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$}  \\
%%\cline{3-12}
& & GC & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 15.68 & 0.96 & 3.69 & 9.50 & 0.15 & 3.11 \\
%%\cline{3-12}
& & RB & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 18.08 & 0.93 & 3.43 & 12.05 & 0.19 & 2.66 \\
\midrule
\textsuperscript{138}Ba & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 4-50\\RIPL-3\\disc.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 1.28 & -1.34 & 2.97 & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$}  \\
%%\cline{3-12}
& & GC & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 5.68 & 0.98 & 3.29 & 2.87 & -0.84 & 3.39 \\
%%\cline{3-12}
& & RB & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 6.06 & 1.67 & 3.29 & 3.35 & -0.09 & 3.37 \\
\cmidrule(l){2-12}
& \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 4-50\\RIPL-3\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.73 & 0.77 & 1.65 & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$}  \\
%%\cline{3-12}
& & GC & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 5.33 & 0.90 & 25.6 & 3.34 & -1.29 & 28.11 \\
%%\cline{3-12}
& & RB & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 6.33 & 1.40 & 29.93 & 3.41 & -0.09 & 30.21 \\
\cmidrule(l){2-12}
& \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 8-21\\Koning\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.73 & 0.70 & 0.52 & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$}  \\
%%\cline{3-12}
& & GC & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 11.21 & -1.22 & 0.62 & 6.33 & -2.25 & 0.67 \\
%%\cline{3-12}
& & RB & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 13.22 & -1.29 & 0.72 & 8.44 & -2.19 & 1.04 \\
\midrule
\textsuperscript{60}Co & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 7-65\\disc.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 1.03 & -1.93 & 1.74 & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$}  \\
%%\cline{3-12}
& & GC & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 5.68 & 0.98 & 3.29 & 3.24 & -0.02 & 1.46 \\
%%\cline{3-12}
& & RB & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 6.05 & 1.66 & 3.28 & 3.57 & 0.43 & 1.46 \\
\cmidrule(l){2-12}
& \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 10-65\\RIPL-3\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 1.17 & -2.54 & 2.31 & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$}  \\
%%\cline{3-12}
& & GC & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 6.95 & 1.26 & 1.91 & 3.94 & -0.46 & 4.23 \\
%%\cline{3-12}
& & RB & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 7.58 & 1.23 & 2.66 & 4.60 & -0.32 & 7.43 \\
\cmidrule(l){2-12}
& \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 7-15\\Koning\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 1.13 & -2.13 & 0.11 & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$}  \\
%%\cline{3-12}
& & GC & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 7.03 & 1.17 & 0.11 & 3.95 & -0.41 & 0.11 \\
%%\cline{3-12}
& & RB & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 7.62 & 1.22 & 0.11 & 4.59 & -0.18 & 0.14 \\
\midrule
\textsuperscript{166}Ho & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 2-154\\disc.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.53 & -1.60 & 76.29 & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$}  \\
%%\cline{3-12}
& & GC & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 13.84 & 1.37 & 69.13 & 7.41 & 0.54 & 63.03 \\
%%\cline{3-12}
& & RB & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 14.37 & 1.54 & 69.34 & 8.18 & 0.78 & 64.23 \\
\cmidrule(l){2-12}
& \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 11-154\\RIPL-3\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.60 & -2.07 & 42.44 & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$}  \\
%%\cline{3-12}
& & GC & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 9.52 & 2.65 & 84.46 & 5.20 & 1.39 & 84.82 \\
%%\cline{3-12}
& & RB & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 9.75 & 3.13 & 86.47 & 5.73 & 1.89 & 88.53 \\
\cmidrule(l){2-12}
& \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 2-16\\Koning\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.56 & -1.49 & 0.79 & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$}  \\
%%\cline{3-12}
& & GC & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 17.76 & 0.78 & 0.48 & 10.96 & 0.08 & 0.43 \\
%%\cline{3-12}
& & RB & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 19.42 & 0.79 & 0.45 & 12.09 & 0.14 & 0.48 \\
\midrule
\pagebreak
\textsuperscript{139}La & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 4-33\\RIPL-3\\disc.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 2.02 & -6.46 & 2.74 & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$}  \\
%%\cline{3-12}
& & GC & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 3.59 & 5.54 & 2.73 & 1.90 & 2.36 & 2.72 \\
%%\cline{3-12}
& & RB & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 3.88 & 6.93 & 2.73 & 2.25 & 3.92 & 2.72 \\
\cmidrule(l){2-12}
& \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 4-33\\RIPL-3\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.78 & -0.76 & 7.40 & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$}  \\
%%\cline{3-12}
& & GC & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 4.27 & 4.11 & 30.97 & 2.08 & 1.88 & 31 \\
%%\cline{3-12}
& & RB & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 4.03 & 6.50 & 31.13 & 2.30 & 3.74 & 31.14 \\
\cmidrule(l){2-12}
& \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 4-21\\Koning\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.79 & -0.88 & 0.94 & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$}  \\
%%\cline{3-12}
& & GC & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 11.63 & -0.01 & 0.91 & 7.07 & -1.08 & 1.23 \\
%%\cline{3-12}
& & RB & {$-$} & {$-$} & {$-$} & 12.94 & 0.02 & 0.97 & 8.42 & -0.95 & 1.51 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) I especially like the use of distinct `\cmidrule`s in the heads of the columns.

Comment: @cfr - Thanks! The main effect of using `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` is, of course, to make the table as wide as the text block. A neat side-effect is that it's not necessary anymore to left- or right-trim a `\cmidrule` to get some visual separation from adjacent `\cmidrule`s.

Comment: @aykutelmas - Be sure to accept (by clicking on the check mark) the answer you find most helfpul.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers in the last 9 columns can be aligned by their decimal dot withe `siunitx` package and I need to use `\multirowcell` (from the `makecell` package) only in the second column, with some adjustment in order to have their contents vertically centred. I added some colour and limited the number of long horizontal rules for a better-looking table.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcolumntype{T}{S[table-format=-1.2]}
\newcolumntype{U}{S[table-format=2.2]}
\usepackage[nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\dimdef\adjA{\dimexpr-\aboverulesep - \belowrulesep-\cmidrulewidth\relax}
\dimdef\adjB{\dimexpr-4\aboverulesep - 4\belowrulesep-4\cmidrulewidth\relax}
\begin{document}

\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{longtable}{ >{\color{Tomato3}}cccS[table-format=1.2]TUUTUUTS[table-format=3.2]}
\caption{aaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aa}\\
\arrayrulecolor{Tomato3}\toprule\arrayrulecolor{black}
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{12}{c}{\tablename~\thetable~ xxxx}\\[1ex]
\cmidrule{2-12}
\endhead
\arrayrulecolor{Tomato3}\bottomrule\arrayrulecolor{black}
\endlastfoot
\multirowcell{2}{\color{black}Nuclei} & \multirowcell{2}{Data\\Range} & \multirowcell{2}{$\sigma$} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{CT} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{BSFG} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{L}\\
\cmidrule(lr){4-6}\cmidrule(lr){7-9}\cmidrule(lr){10-12}
& & & {$T$} & {$\Delta$} & {$χ^2$} & {$a$} & {$\Delta$} & {$χ^2$} & {$a_L$} & {$\Delta$} & {$χ^2$} \\
\arrayrulecolor{Tomato3}\midrule\arrayrulecolor{black}
& \multirowcell{3}[\adjA]{2-82\\RIPL-3\\disc.} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 1.33 & -5.43 & 23.65 & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-12}
& & GC & {--} & {--} & {--} & 5.60 & 4.43 & 23.33 & 3.02 & 2.33 & 23.05 \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-12}
& & RB & {--} & {--} & {--} & 5.84 & 4.91 & 23.34 & 3.36 & 2.97 & 23.11 \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-12}
& \multirowcell{3}[\adjA]{2-82\\RIPL-3\\disc.+res.} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.95 & -3.43 & 31.31 & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-12}
\textsuperscript{76}As & & GC & {--} & {--} & {--} & 9.73 & 1.92 & 58.40 & 5.43 & 0.66 & 79.69 \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-12}
& & RB & {--} & {--} & {--} & 10.70 & 1.81 & 74.46 & 3.75 & 2.42 & 113.09 \\
\cmidrule{2-12}
& \multirowcell{3}[\adjA]{6-27\\Koning\\disc.+res.} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.95 & -3.51 & 1.74 & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-12}
& & GC & {--} & {--} & {--} & 9.90 & 1.97 & 1.48 & 5.80 & 0.67 & 1.34 \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-12}
& & RB & {--} & {--} & {--} & 10.85 & 1.84 & 1.41 & 7.04 & 0.64 & 1.23 \\
\addlinespace
\arrayrulecolor{Tomato3}\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{1-1}\arrayrulecolor{black}
\addlinespace
& \multirowcell{3}[\adjA]{3-91\\disc.} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.81 & -2.69 & 13.61 & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-12}
& & GC & {--} & {--} & {--} & 9.01 & 2.43 & 13.21 & 4.81 & 1.12 & 12.74 \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-12}
& & RB & {--} & {--} & {--} & 9.55 & 2.82 & 13.24 & 5.50 & 1.63 & 12.87 \\
\cmidrule{2-12}
& \multirowcell{3}[\adjA]{13-91\\RIPL-3\\disc.+res.} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.60 & -1.65 & 22.35 & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-12}
\textsuperscript{198}Au & & GC & {--} & {--} & {--} & 15.93 & 0.78 & 60.16 & 9.70 & -0.085 & 99.79 \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-12}
& & RB & {--} & {--} & {--} & 18.47 & 0.70 & 84.45 & 12.38 & -0.11 & 156.17 \\
\cmidrule{2-12}
& \multirowcell{3}[\adjA]{3-91\\Koning\\disc.+res.} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.60 & -1.62 & 4.37 & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-12}
& & GC & {--} & {--} & {--} & 15.68 & 0.96 & 3.69 & 9.50 & 0.15 & 3.11 \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-12}
& & RB & {--} & {--} & {--} & 18.08 & 0.93 & 3.43 & 12.05 & 0.19 & 2.66 \\
\addlinespace
\arrayrulecolor{Tomato3}\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{1-1}\arrayrulecolor{black}
\addlinespace
& \multirowcell{3}[\adjA]{4-50\\RIPL-3\\disc.} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 1.28 & -1.34 & 2.97 & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-12}
& & GC & {--} & {--} & {--} & 5.68 & 0.98 & 3.29 & 2.87 & -0.84 & 3.39 \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-12}
& & RB & {--} & {--} & {--} & 6.06 & 1.67 & 3.29 & 3.35 & -0.09 & 3.37 \\
\cmidrule{2-12}
& \multirowcell{3}[\adjA]{4-50\\RIPL-3\\disc.+res.} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.73 & 0.77 & 1.65 & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-12}
\textsuperscript{138}Ba & & GC & {--} & {--} & {--} & 5.33 & 0.90 & 25.6 & 3.34 & -1.29 & 28.11 \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-12}
& & RB & {--} & {--} & {--} & 6.33 & 1.40 & 29.93 & 3.41 & -0.09 & 30.21 \\
\cmidrule{2-12}
& \multirowcell{3}[\adjA]{8-21\\Koning\\disc.+res.} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.73 & 0.70 & 0.52 & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-12}
& & GC & {--} & {--} & {--} & 11.21 & -1.22 & 0.62 & 6.33 & -2.25 & 0.67 \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-12}
& & RB & {--} & {--} & {--} & 13.22 & -1.29 & 0.72 & 8.44 & -2.19 & 1.04 \\
\addlinespace
\arrayrulecolor{Tomato3}\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{1-1}\arrayrulecolor{black}
\addlinespace
& \multirowcell{3}[\adjA]{7-65\\disc.} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 1.03 & -1.93 & 1.74 & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-12}
& & GC & {--} & {--} & {--} & 5.68 & 0.98 & 3.29 & 3.24 & -0.02 & 1.46 \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-12}
& & RB & {--} & {--} & {--} & 6.05 & 1.66 & 3.28 & 3.57 & 0.43 & 1.46 \\
\cmidrule{2-12}
& \multirowcell{3}[\adjA]{10-65\\RIPL-3\\disc.+res.} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 1.17 & -2.54 & 2.31 & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-12}
\textsuperscript{60}Co & & GC & {--} & {--} & {--} & 6.95 & 1.26 & 1.91 & 3.94 & -0.46 & 4.23 \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-12}
& & RB & {--} & {--} & {--} & 7.58 & 1.23 & 2.66 & 4.60 & -0.32 & 7.43 \\
\cmidrule{2-12}
& \multirowcell{3}[\adjA]{7-15\\Koning\\disc.+res.} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 1.13 & -2.13 & 0.11 & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-12}
& & GC & {--} & {--} & {--} & 7.03 & 1.17 & 0.11 & 3.95 & -0.41 & 0.11 \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-12}
& & RB & {--} & {--} & {--} & 7.62 & 1.22 & 0.11 & 4.59 & -0.18 & 0.14 \\
\addlinespace
\arrayrulecolor{Tomato3}\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{1-1}\arrayrulecolor{black}
\addlinespace
& \multirowcell{3}[\adjA]{2-154\\disc.} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.53 & -1.60 & 76.29 & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-12}
& & GC & {--} & {--} & {--} & 13.84 & 1.37 & 69.13 & 7.41 & 0.54 & 63.03 \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-12}
& & RB & {--} & {--} & {--} & 14.37 & 1.54 & 69.34 & 8.18 & 0.78 & 64.23 \\
\cmidrule{2-12}
& \multirowcell{3}[\adjA]{11-154\\RIPL-3\\disc.+res.} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.60 & -2.07 & 42.44 & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-12}
\textsuperscript{166}Ho & & GC & {--} & {--} & {--} & 9.52 & 2.65 & 84.46 & 5.20 & 1.39 & 84.82 \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-12}
& & RB & {--} & {--} & {--} & 9.75 & 3.13 & 86.47 & 5.73 & 1.89 & 88.53 \\
\cmidrule{2-12}
& \multirowcell{3}[\adjA]{2-16\\Koning\\disc.+res.} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.56 & -1.49 & 0.79 & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-12}
& & GC & {--} & {--} & {--} & 17.76 & 0.78 & 0.48 & 10.96 & 0.08 & 0.43 \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-12}
& & RB & {--} & {--} & {--} & 19.42 & 0.79 & 0.45 & 12.09 & 0.14 & 0.48 \\
\addlinespace
\arrayrulecolor{Tomato3}\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{1-1}\arrayrulecolor{black}
\addlinespace
\multirow{9}{*}{} & \multirowcell{3}[\adjA]{4-33\\RIPL-3\\disc.} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 2.02 & -6.46 & 2.74 & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-12}
& & GC & {--} & {--} & {--} & 3.59 & 5.54 & 2.73 & 1.90 & 2.36 & 2.72 \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-12}
& & RB & {--} & {--} & {--} & 3.88 & 6.93 & 2.73 & 2.25 & 3.92 & 2.72 \\
\cmidrule{2-12}
& \multirowcell{3}[\adjA]{4-33\\RIPL-3\\disc.+res.} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.78 & -0.76 & 7.40 & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-12}
\textsuperscript{139}La & & GC & {--} & {--} & {--} & 4.27 & 4.11 & 30.97 & 2.08 & 1.88 & 31 \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-12}
& & RB & {--} & {--} & {--} & 4.03 & 6.50 & 31.13 & 2.30 & 3.74 & 31.14 \\
\cmidrule{2-12}
& \multirowcell{3}[\adjA]{4-21\\Koning\\disc.+res.} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.79 & -0.88 & 0.94 & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-12}
& & GC & {--} & {--} & {--} & 11.63 & -0.01 & 0.91 & 7.07 & -1.08 & 1.23 \\
\cmidrule(lr){4-12}
& & RB & {--} & {--} & {--} & 12.94 & 0.02 & 0.97 & 8.42 & -0.95 & 1.51
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just a thought for high-end table designers: For the sake of overall appearance of a table, I wonder whether it's better to (a) allow different column widths for the nine numeric data columns (as you do in your answer) or (b) make all column equally wide (as I do in mine). I guess that for arbitrary column contents method (a) must be better because it "always works". For the current table, though, the few deviations from `table-format=2.2` are so insignificant as to maybe make method (b) the better choice. Just a thought...

Comment: @Mico: I wonder if if it is really noticeable without vertical lines,due to the difference of contents within a column (the actual format of a given cell in a 2.2 column, can be 1.2, for instance). I think there is some irregularity in columns that make any general rule impossible to set up.